# Meaning of 'light' in " ... and the LORD hath made to light on him the iniquity of us all."

Tags: word-meaning

What does the word ' light ' mean in this verse from [Isaiah 53:6](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1053.htm):

> " ... and the LORD hath made to **light** on him the iniquity of us all."

Comment: It means to "settle" or "land"; in Modern English we would use *alight*.

Comment: @StoneyB, interesting, thanks. Regarding this as the answer actually.

Answer (score 2):

In the Hebrew souce, the word used is "הפגיע".

This is a verb that appears only twice in the original Hebrew Bible, both in this chaper; the second time is the last word of the chapter (in future tense) and its English translation is ”made intercession".

In modern Hebrew, this isn't a common verb either. It is understood with two very different meanings:

1. Cause hurt, harm deliberately, strike.
2. Plead persistently, entreat.

The second meaning does not make sense here, since the verb refers to the LORD acting on a person; but it is perhaps somewhat related to "intercede", which can explain the translation of the second occurence of the word.

The first meaning may be related to "made to light on" as in burn or light a fire, or perhaps as moving a burden. I don't know whether any of these are common interpretations - just trying to hypothesize on the reason for this translation.

Note that the English translations of the Bible use the Hebrew source as well as the Greek and Latin canonical versions (which are also translations from Hebrew). These are very old texts, end especially in prophecies, some words and even whole sentences are obscure, so translation involves a lot of interpretation, and translation from translation can yield various results. The exact meaning is often a matter of theological debate.

Comment: Thanks, **laugh**. 1) In the first occurrence of the word it does make sense to translate with the first meaning (_"hurt, harm, strike"_) as the translation of the sentence would be: "And G-d **has stricken** him with the inequities of us all." 2) the English verb light is used in the sense _"1: dismount; 2:  settle, alight <a bird lit on the lawn>"_, see one of the _verb_ definitions [here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/light), as **StoneyB** said in the comments. 3) Can **".וְלַפֹּשְׁעִים יַפְגִּיעַ"** be translated as "he **prayed** for the wicked", **not** "interceded"?

Comment: PS: @laugh, I didn't mark your answer as solution, because I believe StoneyB had already given the answer to my question in his comment. Your answer was very helpful nonetheless and I upvoted it.

Comment: Regarding your translation: "pray" is close to the 2nd meaning I listed, but not identical; also, "pray" appears many time in the Bible with a plain translation from the Hebrew verb התפלל. But, as I said, this is a rare word so several interpretations are equally possible. Regarding not marking as answer - that's your call, it's not too important for me :)